# How to print the items with the number less than 9, and number greater than 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program to visualize the items in a list that are smaller than or greater than 9. This is the list I have made:

```
list = [("item1",12.5),("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]
```

I want to be able to print the items with the number less than 9, and then print those with a number greater than 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which provide a simple way to filter lists:

```
l = [("item1",12.5),("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]
[i for i in l if i[1] > 9]
# [('item1', 12.5)]
```

Which is equivalent to the following for loop:

```
new_list = []
for i in l:
    if i[1] > 9:
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
# [('item1', 12.5)]
```

---

Or for values  smaller than `9`:

```
[i for i in l if i[1] < 9]
# [('item', 2.3), ('item', 7.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a list,

```
L = [("item1",12.5),("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]
```

(note avoiding using the keyword `list` as a variable name), you can do a list comprehension, for example:

```
>>> [(item, value) for (item, value) in L if value < 9.0]
[('item', 2.3), ('item', 7.0)]
```

To change the criteria, change the `I`f at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Loop/iterate over items in the list

```
my_list = [("item1",12.5),("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]

for item in my_list:
    if item[1] < 9:  # change <9 to whatever condition you want
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter function as such:

```
original_list = [("item1",12.5),("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]

filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] < 9.0, original_list))
```

printing this:

```
print(filtered_list)

[('item', 2.3), ('item', 7.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
liste = [("item1",12.5),("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]
index=0

while(index<liste.__len__()):
   if liste[index][1] > 9:
      print(liste[index])
   index=index+1
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why the code you provided works.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the values in 2 lists

```
my_list = [("item1",12.5),("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]

less_than_9 = [x for x in my_list if x[1] < 9]
more_than_9 = [x for x in my_list if x[1] > 9]

>>> print(less_than_9)
[("item1",12.5)]
>>> print(more_than_9)
[("item",2.3),("item",7.0)]
```